# No matching distribution found for time Heroku

Tags: heroku, discord.py

I was trying to deploy a python script to Heroku that uses the `time` module in Python. I put the `time` module in `requirements.txt` and Heroku tries to collect it but I get this error:

> No matching distribution found for time

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I put the `time` module in `requirements.txt`

Don't do that.

[`time`](https://docs.python.org/library/time.html#module-time) is part of Python's standard library; it comes with Python and is available automatically.

`requirements.txt` is only for third-party modules. Remove `time` from your `requirements.txt`, commit, and redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Time is a module that is already included with python. This is why you cannot install the module "time" using pip. So if you do not include it in the requirements.txt it will work fine. As Heroku has the python version thus also the time module you need.

Make sure to read the documentation of python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html